# How to build custom PCA function for dimensionality reduction of a 2D image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pca

```
Currently using this function to calculate eigen value and vectors
**np.linalg.eigh**


CODE
cov_mat = image_2d - np.mean(image_2d , axis = 1)
    eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eigh(np.cov(cov_mat)) # USING "eigh", SO THAT PROPRTIES OF HERMITIAN MATRIX CAN BE USED
    p = np.size(eig_vec, axis =1)
    idx = np.argsort(eig_val)
    idx = idx[::-1]
    eig_vec = eig_vec[:,idx]
    eig_val = eig_val[idx]
    numpc = 3 
    if numpc <p or numpc >0:
        eig_vec = eig_vec[:, range(numpc)]
    score = np.dot(eig_vec.T, cov_mat)
    recon = np.dot(eig_vec, score) + np.mean(image_2d, axis = 1).T 
    recon_img_mat = np.uint8(np.absolute(recon))
    return recon_img_mat
```

This code gives me dimensionality reduction although it uses the numpy function. How can I build a custom function for PCA

Comment: Are you just looking to replace `np.linalg.eigh` in the code above? Or do you also want to replace `np.dot`, `np.argsort`, etc...

Comment: just np.linalg.eigh

Comment: Can it be using other built in functions like `np.linalg.svd` or `np.linalg.qr`? Are you looking for an alternative to this specific numpy function, or are you looking to calculate eigenvalues from scratch. The latter can get tricky.